# I am facing issue while saving Datatype of type DateTime in my repository:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

```
name of field :

@Field("publicationDate")
@JsonProperty("publicationDate")
private DateTime publicationDate = null;
```

value that I am sending from json:
"publicationDate": "2020-07-20T09:11:11.11122",

value being saved in Couchbase DB:

publicationDate: 1595236271111

Comment: what is in your dto. Also, it would be better to use ZonedDateTime on entity, and String on dto.

Comment: Because CouchBase transforms your DateTime into a timestamp, which a number. This is its default storage for a DateTime type

Comment: Your date is saved as Epoch which is `GMT: Monday, 20 July 2020 9:11:11.111 AM`

Comment: is there any way to change the default value in couchbase?